# Is there an idiom that suggest you're giving an ultimatum to someone?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that suggest you're giving an ultimatum to someone? Like something similar to "do this or you die!" although I don't think an idiom that use such strong language exist. Is there any idiom like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, an ultimatum can be shortened to just:

> Or else.

Either an ultimatum or a very good offer can be summarized by the following example.  You can replace "Al" and "Bob" with appropriate names or pronouns.

> Al made an offer Bob couldn't refuse.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmX2VzsB25s